# Reconnection Error Stream Management Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, stream-management

i discovered a really big problem (probably mine?) about the XMPP reconnection process in smack library v4.1.5 (Android) and openfire v4.0.1.
I activated the stream management on the client in this way:

```
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);
```

and activated the automatic reconnection in this way:

```
ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(this.xmppConnection).enableAutomaticReconnection();
```

After the first successfull connection and login, when the internet connection goes down and the reconnection process starts I get the following error:

```
W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
    org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: conflict You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions
    <stream:error><conflict xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1003)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:944)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:959)
```

The reconnection manager connects and authenticates very well but then I receive the previous error!
I tried to change the resource also but nothing, it doesn't work!
Someone could help me in understanding what is wrong?

Comment: The exception message itself provides you with some guidance: "StreamErrorException: conflict You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions"

Comment: I know, but no answer found on that link.

Comment: Probably is a bug? The problem seems that I have already a stream openened and resumed, but at the same time i'm kicked out because within the reconnection phase I use the same resource (it is normal). Does someone have experimented the same problem?

Comment: What makes you sure that a stream resumption was tried when you receive the 'conflict' stream error?

Comment: @Flow Because I send the unacknowledged message correctly. Moreover I see this: 'D/SMACK: SENT (1): <enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' resume='true'/>
D/SMACK: RECV (1): <enabled xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>'

Comment: Some Smack or Openfire developer can answer? Is it a normal behaviour? Or can be fixed?